# Id given for a field_set is not persistent in drupal 8

Tags: 8, entities

I gave a id for a field_set from content type management in drupal 8 :

[image]

But after given **`id`** and **`update`**  when i taken again its not taken effect , after typing save also it doesn't worked . Any idea ??

Comment: Did you enable page cache?

Comment: It fixed automatically when i re installed latest **field_group** module

Comment: I think there was a bug in earlier rc4 version